# System.IO exception “The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.”

Tags: c#

Doing a console application where the user inputs an 'account number' that matches with a number in the text file. When number is found, displays information and then a line "if you want to delete this account". When user presses 'y', it should delete the contents of the text file or delete the text file itself.

So far I keep getting this error message: "IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process"

I keep getting this error message on this line of code: File.Delete(textFile)

Here is my code: *I tried writing file.Close() several times to ensure the its no longer being used

```
        Console.WriteLine("Account Number:");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 9);
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        StreamReader reading = File.OpenText("account_number.txt");
        string str;

        while ((str = reading.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (str.Contains(userInput))
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 19);
                Console.WriteLine("Account found!");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(17, 10);

                using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(textFile))
                {
                    while ((userInput = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (counter == 6)
                        { 
                            file.Close();
                            break;
                        }
                        BorderTableTwo();
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(31, 26);
                        Console.WriteLine("ACCOUNT DETAILS");
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(10, y);
                        Console.WriteLine(userInput);
                        counter++;
                        y++;
                        }

                    file.Close();

                    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 19);
                    Console.WriteLine("Delete this acc? (y/n):");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(60, 22);
                    userInput2 = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (userInput2 == "y")
                    {
                        File.Delete(textFile);
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 22);
                        Console.WriteLine("Account has been deleted now");
                        DeleteAccount();
                    }
                    else if (userInput2 == "n")
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        mainMenu();

                    } 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 16);
                Console.WriteLine("Account not found! Try again");
                Console.ReadKey();
                SearchAccount();
            }
        }
        CheckEsc();
```

Comment: Your `StreamReader` is still open. Or one of them at any rate.

Comment: You're completely right. I feel pretty dumb now. I had multiple streamreaders earlier on before the code that I forgot to close